# react-native: how to place a view with position absolute in center of the screen without hide other component

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, expo

I want to center an image inside a view in the center of the screen with           `position: "absolute"` the problem is the view take 100% of the width and height of the screen that's lead to hiding all component under it (an input and button can't be clicked or interact with in IOS).

this is the code:

```
<View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 30,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            backgroundColor: 'red'
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/referralIphone.png")}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{ width: 206, height: 206 }}
          />
        </View>
```

and this is a screenshot form iPhone (with backgroundColor: 'red'):
[image]

this without backgroundColor: 'red':
[image]

the problem is the input and the bottom under it can be clicked because the image hides it

Comment: Remove `flex:1`

Comment: when I remove it the image place at the top left of the screen

Comment: Then you can use top/bottom and right/left styling properties to make it center.

Comment: i tried it but when the keyboard appears the image stays at the center which makes it look bad

Answer (score 0):

Provide **zIndex: 2**, to the wrapper view of the input and button.

Or

Don't keep it absolute try to keep the circle view above the TextInput and give the margin in negative.

Comment: I tried this but the white background appeared on top of the image

Comment: try second solution check comment